# blender: zooming windows and buttons

Tags: blender

I've read that it is possible to zoom in on windows
and buttons in the blender interface. I'm curious,
how is this done? I've googled but cannot find an
answer to this question.

Regards,

John Goche

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clickig Ctrl-Middle Mouse button and move your mouse (vertically on 3D view, horizontally on UI)